# In which file do the export JAVA_OPTS="" Parameters go?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

When I do the following command:

```
root@starwars:/# export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms756m -Xmx756m -Xss128m -Xmn512m"
```

In which file will the values `"-Xms756m -Xmx756m -Xss128m -Xmn512m"` be written?

Answer (score 13):

The startup scripts of tomcat will run a `setenv.sh` file if it exists. Create it (in the tomcat `bin/` ) directory and write your customization there, e.g. that file can just contain the line:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms756m -Xmx756m -Xss128m -Xmn512m"
```

Answer (score 5):

when you do it from the command line, the params are not written anywhere.  They exist only for your current bash session.

Put `export JAVA_OPTS="..."` in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile files to persist them.  If you are on OS X you will have to source the .bashrc file from .profile.

Answer (score 4):

simply add it under startup.sh

like this

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M"
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

The statement just assigns the environment variable **JAVA_OPTS** the given value. There is no file involved here.

Later JAVA_OPTS maybe passed to the command line of java executable

Answer (score 2):

Those values will be used by catalina.sh, e.g.

```
"$_RUNJAVA" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS  $CATALINA_OPTS \
  -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
  -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
  -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
  -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
  >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 &
```

So if you export that variable and then start Tomcat in the same console (e.g. using "catalina start" or "startup") then the JVM will be created with those parameters.

Comment: I wrote the following into /etc/init.d/tomcat6:

if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then
        JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms756m -Xmx756m -Xss128m -Xmn512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+$
fi

restarted, but doesn't take the values.

Comment: You'd have to at least `export` that variable.

Answer (score 1):

you can add them either to the /etc/init.d/tomcat script or /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (or catalina.sh) for when tomcat is started

Answer (score 0):

If you need this configuration only for a specific application you can set it directly in your IDE.

1. Open the "Edit Run/Debug Configuration" dialog
2. click the "Configuration Tab"
3. write the line in the "VM options" field

Run!